# How are the community bouties offered?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Currently these question have a 500 bounty offerer by the community user:
[How can I manually add a subscription to an account using Commerce Subscription Product module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/49105/594)
[What are the implications of duplicate content issues with Drupal comments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/48920/594)
[How do I allow users to just click a marker on an OpenLayers map to go directly to the node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/50058/594)

What are the rules for these bounties to appear ?

Is it normal that they have been put on 3 questions from the same user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user has requested his account to be removed; before doing so, he offered three bounties, which have been re-assigned to the Community user once the account was removed.

Comment: On another note, is it not suspicious that the same user offered the bounty on three questions asked BY the same person?  I was going to ask this but it seemed trivial for it's own question.

Comment: He put the bounties on questions asked from his colleague.

Comment: Yep I saw a decrease in my reputation points :( I wasn't sure this was related, thanks for the clarification.